# how to rename of handle a '-r' named file?

Tags: rename, escape-characters

In a subfolder of my home dir, There is a file called '-r'

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 10240 Sep 15 18:19 ./prog_python/-r
```

I don't even know why.

I would like to rename the file or delete it, but nothing like `rename '/-r' newName` or `rename '\-r' newName` works.
Any advice ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need a "`./`" in the right place:

```
cd ~/prog_python
mv ./-r something
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape anything if you just type out the full path, like

```
mv ~/yoursubfolder/prog_python/-r newName
```

or

```
rm ~/yoursubfolder/prog_python/-r
```

Comment: many thanks ! I've also found this solution, but yours is way more efficient and easy to use : `find . -type f -name '?r' -exec mv {} renamed \;`